# Convert 2-Dimension array to 1-Dimension array in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I want to convert the two dimension array to one dimension array in asp. Is this possible?
If then please give me one example on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far, this question smells of "Please write my code for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will do it for you:

```
Function TransformToSingleArray(TwoDimArray)

 TotalValues = (uBound(TwoDimArray,1) +1) * (uBound(TwoDimArray,2) +1)
 ReDim OneDimArray(TotalValues)
 ArrCnt = 0

 For x = lBound(TwoDimArray,1) to uBound(TwoDimArray,1)
   For y = lBound(TwoDimArray,2) to uBound(TwoDimArray,2)
      EachValue = TwoDimArray(x,y)
      OneDimArray(ArrCnt) = EachValue
      ArrCnt = ArrCnt + 1
   Next     
 Next

 TransformToSingleArray = OneDimArray

End Function
```

Comment: Close, but your code will fail. Your items count is wrong - correct line would be `TotalValues = (uBound(TwoDimArray,1) + 1) * (uBound(TwoDimArray,2) + 1)` please change your code.